# Wrong widget when using QtGui.QInputdDialog.getItem()

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to use QtGui.QInputdDialog.getItem(). 
[According to this source](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qinputdialog.html#details) I am supposed to see the upper left widget from the image below; in reality I get the regular getText widget [image]
What is wrong here? 
Thanks!
This is how I call it (*all_users* is a dictionary of *{user name: user login}*)

```
user_name = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(parent, 'User names',
                                               'Full Name', all_users.keys(),
                                                current=0,editable=False)
```

Comment: can you show how you called it in your code??

Comment: -1 -- without a *minimal working example*, aka [sscce](http://sscce.org/), this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code. In order to get the expected result you must use the `QInputDialog.getItem` instead `QInputDialog.getText`

Change your code to:

```
user_name = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(parent, 'User names',
                                               'Full Name', all_users.keys(),
                                                current=0,editable=False)
```

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion, I fixed my question. I have been changing it back and forth several times - and posted the wrong code, in reality it was _getItem_, _getTex_t would have caused exception with those parameters

Comment: Ok, but the code works fine for me. Can you post some information about `all_users`? It seems to be a dictionary, but also it seems to be the cause of your problems.

Comment: You were absolutely right - the dictionary was empty. Stupid of me to miss! Thanks